# Two definitions for smoothness

Tags: homological-algebra, smoothness, hochschild-cohomology

I'm currently reading Sarah Witherspoon's book on Hochschild Cohomology. At the beginning of the fourth chapter it is given the following definition:

> **Definition 1.** If $k$ is a field and $A$ is a $k$-algebra, we say that $A$ is *smooth* if its Hochschild dimension is finite and it has a finite projective resolution as an $A^e$-module by finitely generated projective modules.

However, in Weibel's book, the definition for smoothness is different (and it is given only for commutative $k$-algebras):

> **Definition 2.** A commutative $k$-algebra $A$ is called *smooth* if for every square-zero extenstion $0\rightarrow M \rightarrow E \xrightarrow{\varepsilon} T \rightarrow 0$ of commuatative $k$-algebras and every algebra map $\nu:A\rightarrow T$, there is a $k$-algebra map $u:A\rightarrow E$ such that $\varepsilon u = \nu$.

As Witherspoon indicate in her book at page 51, these definitions should match for finitely generated commutative $k$-algebra $A$. Why is this so?

Comment: They do not seem to be equivalent in general. The second is called [formally smooth](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00TH) which is satisfied by, say, a polynomial algebra on infinitely many variables.

Comment: What made me think that these definitions are equivalent is that Whitherspoon invoke in the proof of Theorem 3.2.6 (HKR Theorem) a result from Weibel's book on smooth algebras, although she gave a different definition for this notion.

Comment: Also, it seems to me that *formally smooth* means *quasi-free* in Weibel's book (page 313), not *smooth*

Comment: *quasi-free* is noncommutative. Every ring on SP (as in texts in algebraic geometry) is commutative by default. By the way, formal smoothness [coincides](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00TN) with classical smoothness under finiteness.